# How to show array in Json with Fractal?

Tags: php, json, laravel, transform

I want to save REST API data with array to database, its work, all value save to the table, but i still get error when i want to view the result in json.

Here is my error

```
 "message": "Argument 1 passed to App\\Transformers\\NewLoanOfferTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\\Model\\AntiAttrition, array given, called in /home/insko23/testing.insko.my/vendor/league/fractal/src/Scope.php on line 338",
```

My Controller

```html
 public function new_loan_offer(Request $request, AntiAttrition $antiattrition)
    {
         $new = array_map(null, $request->mo_id, $request->id_clrt,$request->TaskID,$request->ACID,$request->CustIDNo);

            foreach($new as $new) {
                $request                  = new AntiAttrition;
                $request->mo_id           = $new[0]; 
                $request->id_clrt         = $new[1];  
                $request->TaskID          = $new[2]; 
                $request->ACID            = $new[3]; 
                $request->CustIDNo        = $new[4]; 
                $request->save();
            }

        $response = fractal()
            ->item($new)
            ->transformWith(new NewLoanOfferTransformer)
            ->toArray();
        return response()->json($response,201);
    }
```

My App\Transformer

```html
<?php

namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Model\AntiAttrition;
use App\Model\SettlementInfo;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class NewLoanOfferTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
 public function transform (AntiAttrition $antiattrition)
 {
  return[
   'id' => $antiattrition->id,
   'mo_id'=> $antiattrition->mo_id,
   'assign_by'=> $antiattrition->assigned_by,
   'id_clrt' => $antiattrition->id_clrt,
   'TaskID'=> $antiattrition->TaskID,
   'ACID'=> $antiattrition->ACID,
   'CustIDNo'=> $antiattrition->CustIDNo
  ];
 }
}
```

I want to show the result in json, like below

```html
{
    "data": [
        {
            "mo_id": "123",
            "id_clrt": "10000000049",
            "ACID": "123",
             .....
        },
        {
            "mo_id": "1234",
            "id_clrt": "10000000045",
            "ACID": "1235",
             .....
        },
        {
            "mo_id": "124",
            "id_clrt": "10000000044",
            "ACID": "1245",
             .....
        },
       ],
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: well `$new` is an array so you probably don't want to be passing that to `item()` in this case, you want to be passing an instance of `AntiAttrition` I would assume

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach loop, avoid using same name for array and elements of the array you are iterating over, you can rename `foreach($new as $new)` to `foreach($newArray as $new)`, or something meaningful with your code logic. Also rather than using `$new[0]` use `$new['mo_id']` for referring to the key of the array